# How to remove marker from openlayers map

Tags: javascript

I have Drupal 7 installation with Openlayers and Geofield (I am using Openlayers as the widget for Geofield). I am able to add new points and show them on the map, however I am not able to remove points from the map once they are edited. I guess that the answer might be pretty simple and I might be doing something wrong, however I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 4):

Finally I managed to deal with it. In case someone else needs the answer:

1. you choose the selection tool (the one with the cross)
2. click on a point and press DEL

Answer (score 1):

Hold down "Delete" and single click the icon you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

And on Mac, I just found out that you need to:
1. select the marker
2. press fn + backspace.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the "selection" tool and then click on a marker while clicking on "Ctrl" (or Shift, I don't remember now).

Answer (score 0):

click the marker you want to delete on the map and then press delete key on the key board repeat the process for each marker you want to delete